# Sumar los Values de varios Select con php

Tags: php, html, select, combobox

Se que les puede parecer muy fácil mi problema:(, pero apenas me están enseñando en la prepa el cómo hacerlo, pero veo que a otros si les funciona el código pero a mi nop:(
Mi problema está en que al darle clic a Enviar, no me arroja la suma:(
Es un programa donde tienes que sumar el valor de los combobox y tener el resultado al darle clic al botón enviar.

[image: Muestra del ejemplo]
Y este es el código:

```
<body>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="asp" value="lavado">Lavado y Aspirado:;

<select name="asp">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="150">$150</option>
  <option value="200">$200</option>
  <option value="250">$250</option>
  </select>
</p>
    <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="sil" value="Silicon">Silicón a Tapicería y Cauchos:;

<select name="sil">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="80">$80</option>
  <option value="100">$100</option>
  <option value="120">$120</option>
  </select>
</p>
    <p>
<input type="checkbox" id="mot" name="mot" value="LavMot">Lavado de Motor:;

<select name="mot">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="100">$100</option>
  <option value="120">$120</option>
  <option value="140">$140</option>
  </select>
</p>
    <p>
<input type="checkbox" id="chas" name="chas" value="LavCha">Lavado de Chasis:;

<select name="chas">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="30">$30</option>
  <option value="35">$35</option>
  <option value="40">$40</option>
  </select>
</p>
    <p>
<input type="checkbox" id="corr" name="corr" value="LavFor">Lavado con fórmula marina anticorrosiva:;

<select name="corr">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="50">$50</option>
  <option value="60">$60</option>
  <option value="70">$70</option>

</p>
    <p>
<input type="checkbox" id="puli" name="puli" value="Pulit">Pulitura del Vehículo:;

<select name="puli">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="90">$90</option>
  <option value="100">$100</option>
  <option value="120">$120</option>
  </select>
</p>

<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar"> &nbsp;  

<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar"> <br/>

<?php

    $num1 = $_POST["asp"];
    $num2 = $_POST["sil"];
    $num3 = $_POST["mot"];
    $num4 = $_POST["chas"];
    $num5 = $_POST["corr"];
    $num6 = $_POST["puli"];
    if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    $resultado= $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4 + $num5 + $num6; 
    echo "El total a pagar es de: "  .$resultado; 
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer una forma, necessitas encajar elementos dentro de `<form>` tag y no lo veo aquí. Por ejemplo,

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="asp" value="lavado">Lavado y Aspirado:;
...
</form>
```

Tambien te recomiendo mover

```
$num1 = $_POST["asp"];
```

debajo de

```
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
```

para evitar esos `Notice: Undefined index ...`

Comment: Graciaaas! Estoy iniciando en esto de la programación, solo que por la contingencia la maestra no nos terminó de enseñar. Mil Gracias Nuevamente.